# Utilizar Core Data con Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift2

Estoy haciendo un juego en Swift con SpriteKit, sucede que no me da la opción para guardar los datos con Core Data.

Lo estoy haciendo guardando los datos en un archivo, pero como son muchos datos mi arreglo es así: `[String : [[String:Any]] ]` y me lanza el error:

```
Cast from 'NSArray?' to unrelated type '[String : [[String:Any]] ]' always fails
```

Incluso si achico el arreglo a algo como esto: `[[String:Any]]` me lanza el mismo error.

Por lo tanto quiero ver si es que puedo guardar los datos en CoreData (aunque nunca lo he utilizado, solo vi un tutorial) y si es así , que alguien me pueda guiar para ver como hacerlo.

Mil gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has de tener en cuenta que utilizar `CoreData` junto a `SpriteKit` no conlleva ningún problema ya que son `frameworks` completamente distintos que.
Para reducir la curva de aprendizaje y implementarlo de forma rápida y sencilla te recomiendo que utilices [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). La documentación es simple y con muchos ejemplos.

En su defecto, y si quieres aprender un nuevo tipo de `storage`
 mucho más rápido y moderno que `CoreData` también puedes utilizar [Realm.io](https://realm.io) que además es multiplataforma.

Comment: Integre CoreData con al ayuda de este tutorial (en ingles): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcQkBYu86h8